# Why user session(in DB) is automaticly unset in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using database to store my user login information, Most of the times when I'm testing user area I redirected to NOT_LOGGED_IN_USER page which has been defined by myself and the session is unset and my login form will appear, here is my config for session:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 100;
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you set your encrytion key in **application/config/config.php**?

Comment: Yes I did, my main problem is that the session is set and I can access it with `$this->session->user_data(...)` but suddenly during my exploring in user area it will redirect to LOGIN page and it says my default message for not logged-in user

Comment: Are you just using codeigniter or are you using a 3rd party library as well?

Comment: I use codeigniter and beside that I use cookie helper to check the login status, is there any 3rd party library that make confusion ? @RossWilson

Comment: No, I was just trying to see if there was another library that you're using that may override some settings. Does this always happen on the same pages or can it be different every time?

Comment: it's different when login status of the user is TRUE and user is exploring his/her userarea with session. @RossWilson

Comment: Are you mainly using ajax requests?

Comment: Yes , I have an SPA in user area with ajax calls, and I forgot to say that I check the login status of the user in the constructor of Userarea-Controller @RossWilson

Comment: Have a look at this: http://blog.jonaszamora.es/en/codeigniter-fix-for-session-loss-caused-by-ajax/ . There are one or two other solutions if you google "codeigniter session ajax"